# Safari and Chrome ignore min-width CSS propery

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

Why do Safari and Chrome ignore min-width CSS property?   Example http://jsfiddle.net/8YFHu/2/ This works in IE and Firefox but not in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Set the `min-width` on the `td` instead of the `table` and it should work fine. See the MDN article for more info on support for `table`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Note - It says that min-width doesn't apply to IE. It looks like it doesn't work in IE7 but 8 and 9 do support it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chrome and Safari simply do not support the `min-width` property on `table` elements. They will, however, respect `min-width` when applied to table cells.

After some quick testing, it appears that support is as follows:

- *Firefox*: Supported (tested in 5, not sure since which version)
- *Internet Explorer*: Supported (since IE8. IE7 and below do not seem to support it)
- *Chrome*: Not supported (all versions as far as I can tell)
- *Safari*: Not supported (all versions as far as I can tell)
- *Opera*: Supported (tested in 11.5, not sure since which version)

More information can be found in the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/min-width) on the property, although the article claims that the property is not supported in IE, even though it is since IE8.

The [CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) states that `min-width` (and `max-width` for that matter) apply to:

> all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row
>   groups

So it would seem that Chrome and Safari are the ones not conforming to the standard.

**Edit**

Having just looked a bit further down the relevant section of the spec, I noticed it then states:

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is
>   undefined.

So it actually looks like no-one got it wrong, and everyone can just do their own thing.

Comment: Update - It appears that Chrome now *does* support this. I'm not sure since when this is the case, but I just tested it in Chrome 19.

Comment: I noticed that Chrome seems to support it when setting the min-width to some number of pixels, but doesn't when setting it to a percentage value. Firefox does in both cases.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, it's often impractical to define widths on td elements. The best workaround I've found for this limitation is to set a min-width on a containing div element for the table.

Comment: I agree with Roland Barker: the best way to ensure min-width for a table is to set min-width on the div that contains the table, and set the table's width to 100%.