# min-width on a table working on the latest of latest IE, Chrome, FF for windows but not Safari 5.1.7

Tags: java, css, gwt, safari

This is similar to some questions that have been asked here before, such as this one: [Safari and Chrome ignore min-width CSS propery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084990/safari-and-chrome-ignore-min-width-css-propery).  I'm using GWT to generate a layout in which I've used CSS to define a `min-width` on one of the panels (which turns out to be a style matched onto a table in the generated JS).  It is working as expected on all of the latest IE, Chrome, FF, but not on the older Safari 5.1.7.

My question is, would it work on the latest Safari on a Mac, or at least on 6.0+?  I don't have access to this atm, so I can't know quickly.  I could possibly fiddle with other CSS properties to get the 'spanning' using min-width to work on 5.1.7 as well, but I wish not to directly modify the JS from GWT java code.

Comment: this was my workaround, since min-width is supported on columns in 5.1.7: `.myClass tbody > tr > td { min-width: 100px; }`

Comment: i discovered [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com), which would be able to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check BrowserStack today, and it does work with 6.