# Why is Safari ignoring min-width and text-align?

Tags: html, css, safari

This piece of HTML renders the word "TEST" on the right side of the page in all browsers except Safari, where the text appears on the left side of the page:

```
<style>
#a{
    min-width: 100%;
}

#b{
    text-align: right;
}
</style>

<body>
<table id="a">
<tr>
    <td id="b">
        TEST
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

What could be causing this, and what workarounds are possible?

Here's a [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/U87aK/)

Comment: Your fiddle shows appropriately on Safari, which is using WebKit for rendering (similar up to recently older versions of Chrome).  Have you tried clearing your cache?  Also what version of Safari are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I duplicated the result.
I saw the text on the `Left` side of the window in Safari version 5.1.8 on a MAC.

I removed the `min-` from the width call and it shows up correctly on the right now..

http://jsfiddle.net/U87aK/2/

Comment: This seems like the right solution. This stackoverflow post has some more info on `min-width` issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084990/safari-and-chrome-ignore-min-width-css-propery

Answer (score 1):

Can't duplicate it on my version of Safari (I'm using version 7.0); however you could maybe achieve the same effect alternatively through CSS's position property.

Try modifying your CSS to this:

```
#a{
    min-width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#b{
    text-align: right;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

**Here's the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z3tT2/

Comment: Didn't work. This throws the test off of the screen on my version of Safari which duplicated his error. I had to adjust your fiddle to a `-29` in order to show the entire word "TEST" http://jsfiddle.net/z3tT2/1/

Comment: @Phlume I'm using Safari v7.0.  Your updated fiddle renders cut off on mine.  At least we're certain this is a browser-compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Safari we can use

```
min-width: 0;
```

since Safari has an issue with min-width: auto; || min-width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* (from a similar, but more complex case) that some older Safari versions ignore CSS tags that are declared id-only (as you do with `#a` and `#b`).

Can you tell me, if this works (for the problematic browser)?

```html
<style>
#a table{
    min-width: 100%;
}

#b td{
    text-align: right;
}
</style>

<body id="a">
<table>
<tr id="b">
    <td>
        TEST
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

NB: This is not how it should be coded, but a demonstration (or not) of the way the browser works.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `min-width: auto` which I duly changed to `min-width: 0` and things are working great.
Another answer that might give some more insights - 
[Safari and Chrome ignore min-width CSS propery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084990/safari-and-chrome-ignore-min-width-css-propery)